# Opening video camera via adb shell command

Tags: android, adb

I've looked high and low, and no luck yet.
I am doing some more camera automation testing on android, and I need a shell way to switch between camera and video camcorder.
Opening the camera itself is pretty straightforward:
adb shell am start -n com.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.CameraLauncher

But once I am in the camera, switching to video (in JB ) is only possible via the floating icon.
Does someone know a way to either open the video camera straight from ADB, or if not possible, switch from video to stills and vice versa?
Thanks in advance
NoamM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
adb shell 'am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE'
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful response.
Do you know of any formal wiki or site which has these types of commands? I keep googling to find specific commands, I am believe there must be a place where they are all kept.
Also, is there a way to automatically choose the default program (disable the popup of choosing which default video recorder is used).